# RewriteRules targeting a directory result in a gratuitous redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirects, url-rewriting

I have a standard CMS-like `RewriteRule` set up in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?slug=$1
```

Let's say I have a directory called `foo` in the root directory. For some reason, if you hit the page it causes a redirect:

`http://example.com/foo` redirects to `http://example.com/foo?slug=foo`

Removing the directory fixes the problem, but unfortunately, it's not an option. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Since `foo` is a real directory on the filesystem, by default `mod_dir` will append a slash, triggering an external redirect (as covener mentions in his answer). I explained more about this in an answer on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31701005/369434

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
DirectorySlash off
```

It's not the rewrite generating the redirect but `mod_dir`.

Answer (score 1):

Before the `RewriteRule` put:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This will check if directory `foo` exists, if it does it won't make rewrite rule.

Also, I'm not sure how you got to `foo?slug=foo` from redirect destination `index.php?slug=$1`?

---

Ok, I've checked, you will need one more ruleset before this one to fix missing `/`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?slug=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

This should work like a charm.